# How to separate content and presentation layers on JSPs?

Tags: html, css, jsp, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have recently started to make some User Interfaces for Websites. What i am currently using something called Bootstrap, which is easy to start with and looks good. But the idea behind does not seem too efficient, since we are making our jsp code (the content) dependent on the css elements like this:

```
<tr class="row col-m-7">
  <td class="column"> ... 
      <a class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> .. </a>
  </td>
  <td class="column"> ... </td>
</tr>
```

Recently the Bootstrap has introduced a newer version (v3), and i had to change many class attributes until the jsp gets a stable look. **I would like to keep the code in separate layers for content and presentation** like this, so i can easily switch my UI framework without loosing any content:

Content (simple html or jstl):

```
   <tr>
      <td>...
      <td>...
    </tr>
```

Presentation:

```
    .. somehow achieving giving a good look to the table above .. (how ???)
```

How can i separate content and presentation layers on JSPs?

Comment: The markup is not content. It really IS part of the presentation layer. There is nothing wrong in having CSS classes in your JSP.

Comment: When you completely change your CSS you will always have to tweak things. Of course you can style a table with CSS just like you can a DIV.

Comment: I don't think so. My content is a link which should direct the user somewhere. How this link should look ("btn btn-xs btn-success") does nothing to do with the content. It is presentation. There is absolutely sth. wrong with those classes. If you do not find it wrong, you are against one of the core principles of software development "separation of concerns".

Comment: CSS is what it is. Deal with it. SO is not a debate site on how the webstandards should have been developed, which is what you seem to want.

Comment: What an answer is that? "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". So you should not have written this comment here, if you knew SO well. If you do not want to join the topic, simply don't. Do not discourage others. I am looking for a solution about my design problem. And there is not anywhere in the world more right than this website.

Comment: "suggest improvements" doesn't mean debate improvements to W3C's specs.  It means suggest how to improve the question.  Here's how to improve your question: Don't ask questions that are just for no purpose but to create debate. Especially debate on something outside everyone's hands.  You aren't going to get all the major browsers to abandon CSS tomorrow for whatever you have in mind by ranting about it on SO.

Comment: I am asking about the separation of CONTENT and presentation. Not Logic and presentation. Servlets are just controllers in an MVC of a frontend architecture. I want to separate Model and View! Moreover this is my post, my question. Why have you been so angry about it like a child, i don't understand? Voting down the question, bringing unnecessary details to the topic.. as i said, like a child. Please stop. This is a question for a purpose! To learn if there is another way of achieving this separation! If you do not know any other way than CSS, it does not mean that there isn't any!

Comment: Take a look at the UPDATE section in my answer below, there is something you may be interested in.

Comment: This is sth. what i definitely looking for. Thank you! Great to see that W3C has doing sth at this topic. In the future we will sure have this separation while others still thinking "CSS what it is". It is pretty bad having so many narrow-minded people here, who think "we already have everything we need", specially for the IT field.. I am very curious what we will have in the future..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A new standard is being developed, called [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-components-intro-20130606/), which will enable developers to create custom html elements which hide the implementation of styling and inner html markup. For example, a modal widget could be declared by the following syntax:

```
<bootstrap-modal>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</bootstrap-modal>
```

Behind the scenes, the developer has specified the actual html markup used to render the widget, that implementation is tied to the custom component.

Here are a few tutorials to get you started:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation

http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/08/introducing-brick-minimal-markup-web-components-for-faster-app-development/

If all `<a>` elements were to look the same, then you could write one css class and all `<a>` elements would have the same styling:

```
a {
    color:blue;
}
```

Some websites, for whatever reason, *possibly* even concerning the **value** of the `href` attribute; will want different colors and styling for different `<a>` elements. The only way to achieve that is with the `class` attribute which refers to a css class from a stylesheet:

```
a.red {
    color:red;
}

<a class="red" href="red.html"/>
```

This means that if you want unique styling for same element names, you will always need to write code which links together the presentation element and the styling.

Comment: All elements would not have to look the same. A webpage usually consists of many separate jsp components where the html components using the same style. So you can theoretically have just one presentation file where you define, which jsp should use which look for which component. So at the end, if sth goes wrong with UI, you just have one file to change.

Comment: And with this updated technology, how do you make a single row in the table red, but the rest blue? A separate jsp file for one row in a table? What about making one letter in a sentence green?

Comment: For those situations you of course have to define sth exclusively. A pointer which then points how it should exactly look in a separate file. I realise that this is actually the idea behind the CSSs.. I think everything would seem better (but not perfect) when we create our own CSSs, and use max. 1 class attribute for each element.

Comment: What if you wanted one small red letter, one small blue letter, one small yellow letter, one small green letter, one large red letter, one large blue letter, one large yellow letter, and one large green letter all in the same word? Would you create eight separate css classes for each color / size combination, or four css classes for the colors and two css classes for the size? You can see that the number of css classes you would need would grow very quickly with a more complicated example. The class names would be ridiculous ex/ `<p class="boldSuperScriptYellowLargeLeftPositioningOpacity9"/>`.

Comment: I think if you have such a requirement, you would have to worry about the requirement itself more than its design :) What i actually looking for would work for the %95 of the websites out there, which have normal designs. Those extreme cases you have always, anywhere. i.e. Javascript where it is not allowed, a html5 tag where it is not supported etc..

Comment: I'm not so sure about that, especially considering that the percentage of websites that use jsp technology is less than 95%. If you look at the css files in some of the open-source libraries, you can see that the complexity is somewhere in between a minimal example such as 4 comments above and the extreme example two comments above. If you want a rich UI design such as provided by such libraries, a certain degree of complexity is required. If things are kept as simple as you suggest then all websites would look like they were created in 1993.

Comment: I will not discuss this with you until morning :) But what i suggest is not that simple. Even Stackoverflow would work nicely. As i see right now, on the right panel there are 3 things right now, the tags of this questions, careers panel and related questions panel. If you write them in different jsps (hopefully) show me an html tag which looks different than others?

Comment: Thank you very much again for the links. Seems very promising. I am intentionally not marking your answer as accepted as the topic seems to be new. We may get some other responses about the Web Components.